# Adding Reversed Numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am solving [SPOJ -ADDREV](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ADDREV/) problem in short  the question is :

> > Reversed number is  For example, 1245 becomes 5421 and 2314 becomes 4132 .
>
> Note that all the leading zeros  are omitted. That means if the
>   number ends with a zero, the zero is lost by reversing (e.g. 1200
>   gives 21).
>   Your task is to add two reversed numbers and output
>   their reversed sum.
>
> Of course, the result is not unique because any
>   particular number is a reversed form of several numbers (e.g. 21 could
>   be 12, 120 or 1200 before  reversing). Thus we must assume that no
>   zeros were lost by reversing (e.g. assume that the original number was
>   12).
>
> Input
>
> The input consists of N cases (equal to about 10000). The first line
>   of the input contains only positive integer N. Then follow the cases.
>   Each case consists of exactly one line with two positive integers
>   separated by space. These are the reversed numbers you are to add.
>
> Output
>
> For each case, print exactly one line containing only one integer -
>   the reversed sum of two reversed numbers. Omit any leading zeros in
>   the output.
>
> Example

Sample input:

```
3
24 1
4358 754
305 794

Sample output:

34
1998
1
```

my code is :

```
ctr=0
up=raw_input()
tocal=raw_input()
while ctr!=int(up):
    l=tocal.split(' ')
    num1=int(str(l[0])[::-1])
    num2=int(str(l[1])[::-1])
    while num1%10 ==0 or num2%10==0:
        if num1%10==0:
            num1=num1[:-1]
        elif num2%10==0:
            num2=num2[:-1]


    sum=int(num1)+int(num2)

    rsum=int(str(sum)[::-1])

    print rsum
    ctr+=1
    tocal=raw_input()
```

while testing in SPOJ it returned Runtime error and in [ideone](http://ideone.com/7ZpSXC) it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prog.py", line 2, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I checked my  code on my pc and the results were correct I don't know what is happening here (I am new to SPOJ and may not know ways of writing code for these type of sites) unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661653/spoj-addrev-problem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276244/spoj-addrev-most-solved-2-with-python) I have not written any code within `raw_input()` then what is happening?

Also my code runs 1 more than desired call(i.e the `raw_input()` call) And I have not found any way to fix it .

Comment: It doesn't look like you provided any input to your program. After correcting that with your ideone [here](http://ideone.com/8l1uiC) I get another error because you're trying to use strings `num1` and `num2` as integers.

Comment: @KurtStutsman I wrote this in codeskulptor and there everything works fine I checked it myself with different inputs

Comment: Not really familiar with codeskulptor, but a quick examination says it runs Python code in browser which means javascript. Javascript is a loosely typed language so it has no problem converting strings into integers on the fly. This represents a bug in their conversion of Python to Javascript. Your code is flawed as it is now.

Comment: @KurtStutsman can you correct the flaw in my code you can edit my code or can give your's

Comment: You wouldn't learn as much if I just give you the answer. But for starters you need to do `int(num1[::-1])` to convert the num1 string into an integer. Same for `num2`. Save those values into variables and then use them to do the rest of your calculations.

Comment: Also don't be afraid to add in some `print` statements within your code to see what values variables have while debugging. You can also use `print repr(var)` where `var` is some variable to see the Python-representation of the value. If you had done `print repr(num1)` you want have seen it was `"42"` instead of `42` without quotes. Also you should use your PC or ideone to test so your'e using a real Python interpreter.

Comment: @KurtStutsman i edited my code in ideone it passed by 9 th line but now the problem is in line 24 with the same error code

Comment: You're not saving your value of `int(num1)` and `int(num2)` like I suggested. For example: `num1 = int(num1[::-1])`. I also don't understand what the `while int(num1)%10 ==0 or int(num2)%10==0` loop is for. I think you should remove that entirely.

Comment: the while loop is for removing 0 at the end of  num1 and num 2 like 1200 to 12

Comment: You don't need that because `int()` will already do it for you.

Comment: @KurtStutsman after editing to this point i am getting `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` in line 3 what to do??

Comment: That's because you're trying to read once you reach the end with your final raw_input(). You don't need that raw_input there. Instead you should move the first `tocal = raw_input()` inside of your first while loop and remove the second assignment to `tocal` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @KurtStutsman thank you for your valuable help now it works fine

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be much more simple:

```
n1 = 754
n2 = 4358
print(int(str(int(str(n1)[::-1]) + int(str(n2)[::-1]))[::-1]))
```

Core:

```
int(str(n1)[::-1]) # convert integer to string, reverse string, convert string to integer
```

You have to do this 2x, once for each integer, then sum, then convert to string, reverse, and back to int.

The 'int' function will automatically strip the leading zeros

Comment: This is a natural approach, but if the goal is to quickly do 10,000 cases then it is possible that all the conversion between ints and lists of strings will be too time-consuming. Hard to know without timing it.

Comment: Takes 0.4 seconds to compute and print 10k cases (rand ints btwn 1 and 10000), and I'm still rocking the T61

Answer (score 0):

A function is required to do all the job for one integer:

```
input = """\
3
24 1
4358 754
305 794
"""

def rev(s):     ## s is an integer
    return int(''.join(list(str(s))[::-1]))

print [ rev(sum(map(rev, x.split()))) if len(x.split()) == 2 else '' for x in input.splitlines() ]

Output:

['', 34, 1998, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```
>>> s='4358 754'
>>> int(str(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(int, [e[::-1] for e in s.split()])))[::-1])
1998
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = int(input()) #Taking number of test cases
if (t > 0): #If test cases are greater than zero
    for _ in range(t): #for all numbers in range of test cases
        n1, n2 = map(int, input().split()) #taking two input numbers in a single line
        print (int(str(int(str(n1)[::-1]) + int(str(n2)[::-1]))[::-1]))
                #convert integer to string, reverse string, convert string to integer and print the sum of these two integers.
```